# Neo4j desktop application gets an Initialization error

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I have just downloaded `neo4j-desktop-1.0.9-setup.exe` and logged in. However, the program is getting `Initialization error: Error: Shasum of the downloaded file did not match the expected value. Please try again!`
Any ideas?

Comment: I think, this challenge is connected to the version of Java. I have already installed Java 8 on my computer. However, Neo4j desktop wants to install it once more. "Getting ready, please wait Downloading Java 8" is on the screen and it throws the same error messae "Initialization error: Error: Shasum of the downloaded file did not match the expected value. Please try again! " when I cik on the "Retry" button.

Comment: Which exact version of Java works fine with neo4j-desktop-1.0.9-setup.exe?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I could not connect to oracle servers because of network problems.so, check if you can connect to oracle website or not.

Comment: Hi @amirahr, I suggest you to answer your own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322394/neo4j-desktop-install-error-in-first-step) and accept your own answer when possible.